# What is this growth in my dog's ear?

Tags: dogs, ears-nose-throat

She was treated for ear infection 2 months ago. On drops and antibiotics. At vet recheck the said she was all good.

We returned a week later because ear was very inflamed and she was in pain. Vet rechecked her again, all good but sent us home with steroid drops to help inflammation.

Day two of inflammation she has this weird growth starting to grow. Vet thinks it was a reaction to the steroids. Four days of pics still looks bad. Is it a tumor?

[image: Inflammation/Growth in ear]

Answer (score 1):

Has the vet seen this photo? I'm not sure what this is but if this were in my dogs ear I'd want to take it back to the vet. From this photo alone those look like larvae or maggots to me? I'm sure it's a pain that you've had to go back to the vet constantly but I think this it's warranted and hopefully since it's a continual recheck of an ongoing issue they won't charge you (my vet usually doesn't for rechecks.)

Comment: Might just be skin tags. Might be something more serious. If you don't trust your vet's evaluation get another vet to give you a second opinion